# Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin creates event and then it is deleted

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm using the createEvent or createEventWithOptions method to create an event silently, the plugin saved in the native calendar, but then the event is automatically deleted.

In this example I have just created a method that is executed by clicking on the button, when clicked it adds an event on August 20th.

I created this video demonstrating the error, as you can see, soon after creating the event it is already automatically deleted.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2a-73yfArVU

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/484

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Thank you